# Where is the error "Use of uninitialized value in string ne" coming from?

Tags: perl

Where is the uninitialised value in [the below code](http://codepad.org/pEwQvELA)?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

my @sites = (undef, "a", "b");
my $sitecount = 1;
my $url;

while (($url = $sites[$sitecount]) ne undef) {
   $sitecount++;
}
```

Output:

```
Use of uninitialized value in string ne at t.pl line 6.
Use of uninitialized value in string ne at t.pl line 6.
Use of uninitialized value in string ne at t.pl line 6.
Use of uninitialized value in string ne at t.pl line 6.
```

Comment: What Terminal means with it's error and how I can solve it

Comment: It means you used an uninitialized value. Solve it by initializing the values on those lines. Next

Comment: I did. Please look at the code first

Comment: my $sitecount = 1;
    my $url;
    my $sysstring;

Comment: I did look at the code, of course. Are you sure that this is your real testcase? There is no `ne` on line 37.

Comment: Yes, I am sure, and therefore I asked what Terminal meant with this error message

Comment: OK. FYI, the Perl interpreter gives you the error, not the terminal. The terminal is just displaying the interpreter's output.

Comment: [I can narrow this testcase down to just 8 lines](http://codepad.org/pEwQvELA). All the rest can be removed in debugging.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't use  `undef` in a string comparison without a warning.

```
if ("a" ne undef) { ... }
```

will raise a warning. If you want to test if a variable is defined or not, use:

```
if (defined $var) { ... }
```

---

Comments about the original question:

That's a strange way to iterate over an array. The more usual way of doing this would be:

```
foreach my $url (@sites) { ... }
```

and drop the `$sitecount` variable completely, and don't overwrite `$url` in the loop body. Also drop the `undef` value in that array. If you don't want to remove that `undef` for some reason (or expect undefined values to be inserted in there), you could do:

```
foreach my $url (@sites) {
  next unless defined $url;
  ...
}
```

If you do want to test for undefined with your form of loop construct, you'd need:

```
while (defined $sites[$sitecount]) {
  my $url = $sites[$sitecount];
  ...
  $sitecount++;
}
```

to avoid the warnings, but beware of autovivification, and that loop would stop short if you have `undef`s mixed in between other live values.

Comment: I just inserted the "undef" because I thought the "$sitecount = 0" could be interpreted as uninitialized. Thx

Comment: @strange way to iterate:
In PHP it works, and variable system looks mostly the same, so I thought that would work...

Comment: You just did, and no, `0` is not the same thing as `undef`.

Comment: I don't see that this answers the question (before or after the edit). Though it may solve the OP's personal problem in a wider manner

Comment: But, my errors are gone, although I don't get output other then opening and searching...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Added a bit about the problem you highlighted with your edit

Comment: @Mat: OK, fair enough, now you covered it all ;)

Comment: WTF, I don't even understand my own post now, cos line 6 is empty

Comment: But, the error is now elsewhere, because I don't get any output other then opening and searching as I just said, but it isn't case sensitive, and before adding multiple sites, I got 183 results from nrc.nl (those sites are all Dutch news sites, this script is just for learning)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I think it is. It is equivalent to `next if (!defined $url);` i.e. skip if `$url` is `undef`.

Comment: I used the first option that Mat did suggest.

Comment: @Mat: Ah, yes, I'm with you. I misread `next` as some form of `continue` without which the loop would break. Silly me!

Comment: @11684: your code finds 176 matches for `nrc.nl` with my first suggested change, as long as you remove the `$url = 'whatever';` in the loop body. (You don't want to do that, and the url you force in there is invalid.)

Comment: A simple `last unless defined $url;` would work instead of the while construct.

Answer (score 6):

The correct answers have already been given ([`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) is how you check a value for definedness), but I wanted to add something.

In [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) you will read this description of `ne`:

> Binary "ne" returns true if the left argument is stringwise not equal
>   to the right argument.

Note the use of "stringwise". It basically means that just like with other operators, such as `==`, where the argument type is pre-defined, any arguments to `ne` will effectively be converted to strings before the operation is performed. This is to accommodate operations such as:

```
if ($foo == "1002")  # string "1002" is converted to a number
if ($foo eq 1002)    # number 1002 is converted to a string
```

Perl has no fixed data types, and relies on conversion of data. In this case, `undef` (which coincidentally is not a value, it is a function: `undef()`, which *returns* the undefined value), is converted to a string. This conversion will cause false positives, that may be hard to detect if `warnings` is not in effect.

Consider:

```
perl -e 'print "" eq undef() ? "yes" : "no"'
```

This will print "yes", even though clearly the empty string `""` is not equal to `not defined`. By using `warnings`, we can catch this error.

What you want is probably something like:

```
for my $url (@sites) {
    last unless defined $url;
    ...
}
```

Or, if you want to skip to a certain array element:

```
my $start = 1;
for my $index ($start .. $#sites) {
   last unless defined $sites[$index];
   ...
}
```

Same basic principle, but using an array slice, and avoiding indexes:

```
my $start = 1;
for my $url (@sites[$start .. $#sites]) {
    last unless defined $url;
    ...
}
```

Note that the use of `last` instead of `next` is the logical equivalent of your while loop condition: When an undefined value is encountered, the loop is exited.

More debugging: http://codepad.org/Nb5IwX0Q

If you, like in this paste above, print out the iteration counter and the value, you will quite clearly see when the different warnings appear. You get one warning for the first comparison `"a" ne undef`, one for the second, and two for the last. The last warnings come when `$sitecount` exceeds the max index of `@sites`, and you are comparing two undefined values with `ne`.

Comment: `()` has a higher precedence than `ne` or `=`. `while (($url = $sites[$sitecount]) ne undef) { ... }` clearly has a second set around `$url = $sites[$sitecount]`

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the message would be better to understand if it was:

```
You are trying to compare an uninitialized value with a string.
```

The uninitialized value is, of course, `undef`.

To explicitely check if `$something` is defined, you need to write

```
defined $something
```

Answer (score 3):

`ne` is for string comparison, and `undef` is not a string:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
('l' ne undef) ? 0 : 0;
```

> Use of uninitialized value in string ne at t.pl line 3.

It does *work*, but you get a [slightly confusing] warning (at least with `use warnings`) because `undef` is not an "initialized value" for `ne` to use.

---

Instead, [use the operator `defined` to find whether a value is defined](http://codepad.org/NOQze0c1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;

my @sites = (undef, "a", "b");
my $sitecount = 1;
my $url;

while (defined $sites[$sitecount]) {   # <----------
   $url = $sites[$sitecount];
   # ...
   $sitecount++;
}
```

... or loop over the `@sites` array more conventionally, as Mat explores in his answer.